# Will this lua code work to download certain files on my GMOD server

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I have recently been building my GMOD server and is slowy getting popular but I was interested to create a addon so I put together something that, should, download some worksop links in loading screen and others ingame. This is what I have created.

sv_auto_download:

```
// Write the map download codes below

resource.addworkshop( "" )


function DownloadFiles() 

    // Write the the texture codes below

    resource.addworkshop( "" )
    return ""
end
hook.Add ( "PlayerInitialSpawn", "DownloadFiles" )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this will not work.
Firstly, `PlayerInitalSpawn` runs *after* the loading screen and also `resource.addworkshop` is a server side function that is loaded once so that the server knows to load the workshop files, meaning addons will still be downloaded in the loading screen anyhow.

You can not *"download some worksop links in loading screen and others ingame"* and you should not force players to download 10gigs of models if they don't want to.

The best way to get players to download addons is through the workshop.

1. Create a **collection** on the steam workshop for your addons, for example http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1244735564
2. Head over to http://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey and use your *server's IP address* as the website and save your **api key** somewhere safe (i.e. don't share it)
3. Go to your **launch options** for scrds.exe (either a .bat file or in the server dashboard) and add `-authkey 3XAMPL3K3YF0RTH3T3ST3 +host_workshop_collection (collection ID)`, with the collection ID being the `?id=1244735564` part of the collections URL

Then, players will automatically download server content and it is easy for you to add more addons, with it also serving as a way for players to quickly download large models permanently if they wish to play on your server for an extended period of time.

By the way, you forgot to include the function delegate into the `hook.Add`:

`hook.Add ( "PlayerInitialSpawn", "DownloadFiles", DownloadFiles )`

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. At the moment I have what you are saying about the launch options AND recource.addworkshop AND an addon that does it all for me. When I only did the launch options it never worked properly and people ended up with lot of errors

Comment: Did you make a collection? Can you send me the launch options you put in?

Comment: Yes 1 moment. https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1131625268

-authkey [MY AUTH KEY FROM THE SITE] +host_workshop_collection 1131625268

Comment: Using this method will only result in the server downloading the content not joining clients. You still need the add workshop calls to get clients to download any content that isn't a map (those are done automatically). Also, it's `resource.AddWorkshop(id)`, Lua as with most programming languages is case sensitive.

Comment: @VosemMedia is it a .bat file or something in a server dashboard? can you sende *all* of the launch options you have together?

Comment: A bat file which which is on my dedicated server in my garage.




 @echo off
cls
echo Protecting srcds from crashes...
echo If you want to close srcds and this script, close the srcds window and type Y depending on your language followed by Enter.
title srcds.com Watchdog
:srcds
echo (%time%) srcds started.
start /wait srcds.exe -console -game garrysmod +map rp_evocity2_v5p +maxplayers 20 -authkey [AUTHKEY] +host_workshop_collection 1131625268
echo (%time%) WARNING: srcds closed or crashed, restarting.
goto srcds

Comment: We are getting away from the real question, can someone help me make this addon to work? Thanks